# QueryString different from RawUrl

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to pass a parameter containing space to a page. 
When I look at the `Request.RawUrl`, I see that spaces are replaced by '%20' but why when I look at `Request.QueryString` spaces are replaced by '+' ?
How can I fix that so `Request.QueryString`contain space or at least '%20%' ?
Thansk for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I found the following RFC:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866
It states the following:

> An HTML user agent begins processing a form by presenting the
> document with the fields in their initial state. The user is allowed
> to modify the fields, constrained by the field type etc.  When the
> user indicates that the form should be submitted (using a submit
> button or image input), the form data set is processed according to
> its method, action URI and enctype.

The default encoding for all forms is `application/x-www-form-    urlencoded'. A form data set is represented in this media type as

> follows:
>
> 1. The form field names and values are escaped: space
>    characters are replaced by '+', and then reserved characters
>    are escaped as per [URL]; that is, non-alphanumeric
>    characters are replaced by '%HH', a percent sign and two
>    hexadecimal digits representing the ASCII code of the
>    character. Line breaks, as in multi-line text field values,
>    are represented as CR LF pairs, i.e. `%0D%0A'." ...   The user might edit the fields and request that the form be
>    submitted. At that point, suppose the values are:
>
>    name "John Doe"
>
>    gender "male"
>
>    family "5"
>
>    city "kent"
>
>    city "miami"
>
>    other "abc\ndefk"
>
>    nickname "J&D"
>
>    The user agent then conducts an HTTP POST transaction using the URI
>    `http://www.w3.org/sample'. The message body would be (ignore the
>    line break):
>
>    name=John+Doe&gender=male&family=5&city=kent&city=miami&
>    other=abc%0D%0Adef&nickname=J%26D

The previous note refers to Form Submission.
I believe that the .net method you are using is following the previous rules for some reason: seems to be processing the query string following the rules to process the Body of a POST request (note the John+Doe parameter). Perhaps you can specify that the method should process a GET request not a POST request? ¿Something in your request makes the method to process it as a POST?

Regards,

Comment: Thanks I already use this. As you can see, the problem is not this one. My raw url is correctly  formatted. It's the Request.QueryString that replace %20 by +. For example, when I see 'page.aspx?arg1=hello%20you' using `RawUrl`, `QueryString` show 'hello+you'. My question is : Why this behavior ?